Magento 2: Unique Constraint Violation Error on Saving Custom Product Attribute After Database Migration
I've recently migrated my Magento 2 project's database from the production environment to a local setup to perform a version upgrade. Since the migration, whenever I attempt to save any custom product attribute, I encounter the following error:
"Unique constraint violation found"


Try run this query to find any duplicate
SELECT entity_id, attribute_id, COUNT(*) as duplicate_count
FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal -- replace 'varchar' with 'int', 'decimal', etc., depending on the attribute type
GROUP BY entity_id, attribute_id
HAVING duplicate_count > 1;

